# How to get a specific array value from the array of Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really really newbie in javascript and jquery. I am now making a calculator.

This is my code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var buttonname = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "+", "-", "*", "/", "C", "Enter", "="];
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
          // for(var i=0;i<buttonname.length;i++){
          var arrayvalue = buttonname[ ? ? ? ? ? ];
          var calculate = $("<p>" + arrayvalue + "</p>");
          $("#result").append(calculate);
          //}
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--<textarea id="numberarea"></textarea><br>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      for (var i = 0; i < buttonname.length; i++) {
        document.write("<button>" + buttonname[i] + "</button>");
        if (i != 0 && (i % 4) == 0)
          document.write("<br>");
      }

    </script>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

How should I do with line `var arrayvalue = buttonname[]` or with click function to get a specific value from the array in my case?

Comment: `var arrayvalue = buttonname[x]` where `x` is the specific value you wish to retrieve, starting from 0.

Comment: Could you attach the name as a property of the button so you could reference it that way?

Comment: `this.innerText` instead of `buttonname[?????]`?  Otherwise, store it as a `data-` attribute.  If you're determined to reference it by index (by using the `buttonname[?]` syntax), you'd have to somehow figure out the index of the button you pressed, but because it's nestled in with break tags, it'll be way more work than it's worth.

Comment: @ObsidianAge nono.. it is not so simple. I understand your code but your advice only prints out the value which is in the x-th index but I want if I click on the first button, 1 would be printed out, 2nd button, 2 should be printed out. So it should print out different values every time.

Comment: @BenjaminCommet sorry may be no...? Newbie.. hehe.. Learned only few lessons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an attribute to each button when you create them, and then reference that attribute from the event argument of your click handler. Something like this:

```js
var buttonname = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","+","-","*","/","C","Enter","="];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(ev){
   // for(var i=0;i<buttonname.length;i++){
        var arrayvalue = buttonname[$(ev.target).attr('data-index')];
        var calculate = $("<p>"+arrayvalue+"</p>");
        $("#result").append(calculate);
    //}
  });
});

for(var i = 0; i <buttonname.length; i++){
  document.write("<button data-index="+i+">"+buttonname[i]+"</button>");
   if(i != 0 && (i%4) == 0)
   document.write("<br>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works! Actually I don't understand what does attr('data-index') mean now but you saved me!

Comment: You can see on the document.write line I'm setting an attribute on the button HTML element: `"<button data-index="+i+">"`. The `.attr()` function is a jQuery method for getting the value of the attribute with that name.

Comment: aha! Now I understand! Thank you very much!

Comment: For event listeners, the callback function will be passed an `Event` object as the first argument. This event object contains information about the event; `ev.target` is the element which triggered the event (in this case, the individual button).

Comment: Thank you! I just thought that is really similar like java